# loading all lua files in a directory

Tags: lua

I am trying to "import" every file in the specified directory to a table but when i look at the output it only shows **one** imported file.

with "import" I mean `require(dir.."/"..name)` this will return a value witch will be put in the $table at position "name" so this looks like $table[name]

I have made the following code but it does not work for me.. I hope someone can tell me what I am doing wrong..

**(the code below is simplified but does include all the files, structures and code associated with this function, also i have inserted print() and printTable() for debugging purposes)**

I work on a Debian Jessie machine

**file structure**

```
~/x/main.lua
~/x/folder/file1.lua
~/x/folder/file2.lua
~/x/folder/file3.lua
~/x/folder/file4.lua
~/x/folder/file5.lua
```

**./main.lua** ([printTable script](https://github.com/subject546/lua-printTable))

```
local printTable = require "printTable"

-- scan dir and add the file contents (name ,function(if .lua), filepath from script) to a table
function appendDir(functiontable,dir)
  for filename in io.popen('dir "'..dir..'" -1'):lines() do
    print(filename)
    local path = dir.."/"..filename
    local name = filename:sub(1,filename:len()-4)
    print(name)
    local tempValue = false
    if filename:sub(filename:len()-3,filename:len()) == ".lua" then tempValue = require(dir.."/"..name) end
    functiontable[name]={["value"]=tempValue,["path"]=path}
    printTable(functiontable)
  end
  print("---")
  printTable(functiontable)
end

local table1 = {}
appendDir(table1,"./folder")

print("")
print("table1:")
printTable(table1)

for key,value in pairs(table1) do
  value.value()
end
```

**./folder/file*.lua** all the files are build in the same way only the function returns a different string.

```
function func()
  return "$string"
end

return func
```

the following strings are for the different files and are inserted in the **$string** position

```
~/x/folder/file1.lua   $string=string of file 1
~/x/folder/file2.lua   $string=string of file 2
~/x/folder/file3.lua   $string=string of file 3
~/x/folder/file4.lua   $string=string of file 4
~/x/folder/file5.lua   $string=string of file 5
```

now when i execute the main.lua script i get:

```
~/x $ lua -v
Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
~/x $dir folder -1
file1.lua
file2.lua
file3.lua
file4.lua
file5.lua
~/x $ lua main.lua
file1.lua
file1
[file1][value] ->       TYPE == function
[file1][path] ->        VALUE == ./folder/file1.lua
file2.lua
file2
[file1][value] ->       TYPE == function
[file1][path] ->        VALUE == ./folder/file1.lua
file3.lua
file3
[file3][value] ->       TYPE == function
[file3][path] ->        VALUE == ./folder/file3.lua
file4.lua
file4
[file3][value] ->       TYPE == function
[file3][path] ->        VALUE == ./folder/file3.lua
file5.lua
file5
[file4][value] ->       TYPE == function
[file4][path] ->        VALUE == ./folder/file4.lua
---
[file4][value] ->       TYPE == function
[file4][path] ->        VALUE == ./folder/file4.lua

table1:
[file4][value] ->       TYPE == function
[file4][path] ->        VALUE == ./folder/file4.lua
```

Comment: how function printTable implement?

Comment: The error is in your "printTable".  Why do you return from inside of for-loop [here](https://github.com/subject546/lua-printTable/blob/master/printTable.lua#L8)?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff it should return to the "callLocal" function inside the "printTable" function thisway the function can call itself while it does not know its own name or pointer... the basic idea being that the local printTable function is always present and the loop can call it multiple times for tables pointing to tables shown in the output as `[x][1]="y"`, this will look something like `table1={["x"]={[1]="y"}}; printTalbe(table1)` in code

Comment: @zzn the printTable function is on github [https://github.com/subject546/lua-printTable/blob/master/printTable.lua](https://github.com/subject546/lua-printTable/blob/master/printTable.lua)

Comment: @subject546 - You are returning from inside for-loop, so you can not continue that loop, that's why only one table is displayed.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I SEE! HOW STUPID OF ME!! thank you for pointing that out! I have fixed it now and it does seem to be working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @EgorSkriptunoff pointed out in the comment section of the original post it was a bug in the printTable function where the function returned to the for loop instead of the internal function. this has been resolved and committed to github!

Thank you for your help!